# Rest easy and jackson how did it work out of the box?

Tags: rest, jboss, jackson, jax-rs, resteasy

I was trying to create a rest service using RestEasy which would produce JSON output. I used RestEasy 2.2.1.GA +  JBoss 7.1 .  I didnt configure any of Jacson dependencies in my POM file neither did I configure anything related to Jacskon in my web.xml file but the JSON conversion worked out of the box for me . This is my web.xml

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
<display-name>Restful Web Application</display-name>

<!-- Auto scan REST service -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- this need same with resteasy servlet url-pattern -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
    <param-value>/rest</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

and this is my service class

```
package com.ajbose.test;


import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/message")
public class MessageRestService {


@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Student printMessage() {
    Student student = new Student("Ajay","bose",12,21);
    return student;
    }
}
```

How did it work ? 
Even in the example that I followed I am not able to find any jacskon configurations for data bindinding.

I want to use https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind for my JSON conversions. What configurations do I have to change so that the Appserver would make use of it.

I know its too many questions. It would be enough if you could point me to a right book/link to read. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resteasy by default is configured with support for Jackson 1.x out the box. It has this module

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
   <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
   <version>2.2.1.GA</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

along with the Jackson dependencies configured. If you want to do any configuration to Jackson serialization/deserialization, you can add that Maven artifact in a `provided` scope. Then configure the `ObjectMapper` inside a [`ContextResolver`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/ContextResolver.html). For example

```
@Provider
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class ObjectMapperContextResolver implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {
    private final ObjectMapper mapper;

    public ObjectMapperContextResolver() {
        mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        // configure mapper
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> cls) {
        return mapper;
    }
}
```

The `ContextResolver` should be picked up from the scanning with the `@Provider` annotation.

Note the above is using Jackson 1.x (the Codehaus version). To use the FasterXml version, instead of the above dependency use

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
   <artifactId>resteasy-jackson2-provider</artifactId>
   <version>2.2.1.GA</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Only different is the `jackson2`. Then you need to set up the `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` file in your `WEB-INF`, as mentioned [here](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.2.Final/userguide/html/json.html#d4e1044)

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
           <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson-provider"/>
        </exclusions>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson2-provider" services="import"/>
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Here, you're basically disabling the default Jackson 1.x and deploying 2.x. Either way the `ContextResolver` will be fairly similar, except for the different `ObjectMapper` namespaces, and of course the different style configurations for the `ObjectMapper`.

Each time serialization/deserialization needs to be done for requests and responses, the `getContext` method will be called to retrieve the `ObjectMapper`.

---

**UPDATE**

So after some testing, it seems the Maven dependency I have above is not in Maven central. I'm guess it's in a different Repo. Anyway I just changed the version to `3.0.9.Final` just to get the Jackson compile-time dependencies. But it's still in a provided scope, so it won't be used on deployment. JBoss will use it internally provided module.

Comment: I added the  jboss-deployment-structure.xml , but still no luck , The annotations are not getting honoured

Comment: @Ajay Yeah I don't know, it works perfectly fine for me. I just tested it. I had to change the Maven dependency version to `3.0.9.Final` because I guess the 2.x.x versions aren't in Maven central, but doesn't really matter, I had `<scope>` as `provided` so it wouldn't be used, only to compile. I only used it for the Jackson annotations. Can you show what annotations are you are using.

Comment: Just to let you know what I did, I just created a Maven webapp (in Netbeans), it comes with `javaee-api` as the only depedency, I add the depedency above (the second one), with the 3.0.9.Final version, I copy and pasted your exact web.xml, copy and pasted the jboss-deployment-structure.xml into the WEB-INF and create a simple Student and StudentResource class. I annotated the Student getters with @JsonProperty and just change the name. When I ran it, the @JsonProperty is picked up and names changed. I Tested in JBoss 7.1.1